# How can I take advantage of Postgres row-level-security in a Laravel application?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, row-level-security

I am currently experimenting with adopting PostgreSQL [row-level security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) for a server-side application in Laravel. My goal is to move multi-tenancy access rights into the DB, so as to completely remove them from application logic. This requires me to add a `SET app.tenant = 'current_tenant_id'` statement to the beginning of all database sessions. This needs to happen for both Eloquent ORM queries and raw `DB` queries.

So far, I've experimented with two approaches:

**Modifying the query in a listener**

This did not work because `DB::listen` callbacks trigger after the query has been executed. I could not find any other callbacks or Laravel Events that seemed appropriate.

**Using HTTP middleware**

```php
DB::statement("SET app.tenant = '<current_tenant_id>'");
```

This seems to work, but it is less than ideal for a few reasons:

1. It will break if I ever switch to [separate read/write connections](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#read-and-write-connections), because this code will choose a connection to operate on before performing any other DB operations.
2. It's an incomplete solution, as it does not address, for example, background jobs. I could implement this in a background job base class, but that solution then suffers from the same problem as 1.

It also seems that I may be swimming upstream here, as I've yet to find any libraries, tutorials, or write-ups by anybody else attempting to do this. All of the many Laravel tenancy libraries I have looked at seem to rely entirely on either connection switching (multi DB) or WHERE clause (single DB) solutions.

Is there a way I can take advantage of row-level security from within Laravel, in a way that is mostly transparent to the development team?